# how to Check file availability Async

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to check all my c# Application files in startup if they are exist or not.
this code will do it :

```
 if (!File.Exists("MyControls.dll")
{
 return false;
}
```

IS File.Exists an IO ? will it freezes main thread (UI) ? there is no any File.ExistsAsync. how can i check file availability Async ?

I tried some other ways but they all freeze app when file not exist because of FileNotFoundException

This is other code example, I have created a bunch of empty txt files for test:

```
private static async Task<bool> ReadAsync(Encoding encoding)
{
 bool x = true;
 for (int i = 1; i < 25729; i++)
  {
   string filename = " (" + i.ToString() + ").txt";
   try
    {
     char[] result;         

     // File.OpenText : if file not exist a FileNotFoundException will 
     // accur and it will freeze UI 
     using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename)) 
      {
       result = new char[reader.BaseStream.Length];
       await reader.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)reader.BaseStream.Length);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     x = false;
    }        
  }        
  return x;
}
```

It freezes UI when files not exist, but when they are exist it slow down UI not completely freeze.

Is this approach correct for Check file availability of not can you help me how i do it ?

**Update 1 :**

I have this Function :

```
private bool ISNeededFilesAvailable()
{     
 if(!File.Exist("MyCustomeControls.dll"))
  return false
 if(!File.Exist("PARSGREEN.dll"))
  return false
 .
 .
 .
return true
}
```

I am not sure where and when use this method ! but i used it in Loaded event of a window named startupWindow and i call showdialog() before mainwindow opens :

```
private void StartupWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    if (!ISNeededFilesAvailable())
     Application.close();
    else
     this.close();
   }


  public MainWindow()
   {
       StartupWindow sw = new StartupWindow ()
       sw.showdialog();
       InitializeComponent();
   }
```

Comment: What? `File.Exist` simply checks if the file exist. It shouldn't freeze or slow down anything, at least to a noticeable extent since there's no real read or write performed on the file.

Comment: File.Exist is an IO or not ? are you sure  It shouldn't freeze or slow down anything !? if yes problem is solved and thank you very much :)

Comment: "Is this approach correct" - depends on how you call this. WPF + async/await means: show the whole call-chain.

Comment: Checking for  25729 files will take some time. Is this really your requirement?  How many do you expect in real life?

Comment: Your algorithm sucks. You could just `return false;` from the catch block. But I suspect we're not looking at real code.

Comment: You want to check your file exists or not, can you please tell us that what you want to do if any file not exists? If not exist then also you want to open your application or not? please clear that will help you to provide exact code, or file exist you are storing and then displaying in any other control, if you want to see the status after application launch then you can make thread and let the thread work in background. If you want to check before launch then you can apply some wait for background thread to be completed.

Comment: 25729 is not real. its just for test to see if it freezes UI or not just for research !!!

Comment: thank you yes this algorithm sucks ! but is not a real algorithm. it just for test !! how can i test freezing of UI !?

Comment: i want do two things. first my application have some needed files MyCustomeControls.dll, Stimulsoft.Report.dll and etc, I want to check availability  of them and  second, I want to do check file availability  Async. And Yes if MyCustomeControls.dll is not exist then my application will not work ! application will not open ! but if  Stimulsoft.Report.dll not exist , it is just a warning ! report will not work, not application

Comment: Start by showing how, where and when you call this from the GUI (or ViewModel). The start and end of async/await matter the most.

Comment: Simplifying your code is a good idea but then make sure you have a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you  bommelding i have an Update on my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your function in a Task - this will move execution from UI thread to the bacckground:

```
private Task<bool> ISNeededFilesAvailable()
{ 
    return Task.Run(()=>{   
       try{
       IsBusy = true; 
       if(!File.Exist("MyCustomeControls.dll"))
         return false
       if(!File.Exist("PARSGREEN.dll"))
         return false

       return true;
       }
       finally
       {
          IsBusy = false;
       }
    });
}

private async void StartupWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    if (! (await ISNeededFilesAvailable()))
     Application.close();
    else
     this.close();
   }
```

You can use IsBusy to display for example indeterminate ProgressBar to show user that something is happening. Maybe even change cursor for better feedback.